# Trying to get a div positioned over two others either relatively or absolute

Tags: css, css-position

HTML:

```
<div id="outer1">
    <div class="bg">
        <div class="top"></div>  
        <div class="base"></div>  
    </div>  
    <div class="content"></div>
</div>
<div id="outer2">
    <div id="bg">
        <div class="top"></div>  
        <div class="base"></div>  
    </div>  
    <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

CSS2:

```
div { width: 100%; }

#outer1, #outer2 {position: relative;}
#outer1 .top { height: 200px; background-color: blue; } 
#outer1 .base { height: 200px; background-color: yellow; } 

#outer2 .top { height: 200px; background-color: green; } 
#outer2 .base { height: 200px; background-color: yellow; } 

.content { 
    width: 160px; margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative; bottom: 250px; height: 300px; background-color: white; border: 1px solid black;}
```

[This is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FSXj8/16/)

The white, black-bordered div (`.content`) is supposed to sit on the split-coloured background (`.bg`) (as it is).

Using relative positioning - but the space i've told it to move up by (250px), is still been taken by it's parent (`#outer1`). (there's a gap between to the two 'outer' divs - they should be touching)

I tried absolute positioning but because the content div is taller than the relative content, the height is not honoured. And becuase it's dynamic content I cannot give it a fixed height (although i did for illustration)

One option is javascript, another is using a background-repeater for the top half.

Can it be achieved with pure CSS2?

Answer (score 3):

Edit: Complete rewrite...

Here is the new fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FSXj8/14/

Okay so I took the liberty to start from scratch.  Here is the html

```
<div id="outer1" class="container">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="innerContent">hello world</div>
    </div>
    <div class="top"></div>
    <div class="base"></div>
</div>
<div id="outer2" class="container">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="innerContent">hello world</div>
    </div>
    <div class="top"></div>
    <div class="base"></div>
</div>
```

And here is the CSS

```
div {
    width: 100%;
}
.container {
    height: 400px;
    display: table;
    position: relative;
}
.top, .base {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    height: 50%;
    z-index: 0;
}
.top {
    top: 0;
}
.base {
    bottom: 0;
}
#outer1 .top {
    background-color: blue;
}
#outer1 .base {
    background-color: yellow;
}
#outer2 .top {
    height: 50%;
    background-color: green;
}
#outer2 .base {
    height: 50%;
    background-color: yellow;
}
.innerContent {
    min-height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: white;
    width: 100px;
}
.content {
    display: table-cell;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: transparent;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: not quite, if content is 400px; it doesn't make it's parent grow as I've mentioned in my post, absolute positioned elements cannot do this. content cannot have a fixed height.

Comment: +1 for effort, but sorry i probably havent explained myself properly - content is dynamic it wont be 100px ever, it will always be taller than .bg. .bg.base should grow to fit...

Comment: I just set the min-height for display purposes, remove it and see that it fits to the content.  Add as much content as you want and watch the container grow.  Here it is with no min-height http://jsfiddle.net/FSXj8/19/ and here it is with a lot of content http://jsfiddle.net/FSXj8/20/

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you want, you said something about not using absolute:

```
.content { 
width: 100px; margin 0 auto;
position: absolute; margin-top:-250px; height: 100px; background-color: white; border: 1px solid black;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FSXj8/7/

Comment: not quite, if content is 400px; it doesn't make it's parent grow as I've mentioned in my post, absolute positioned elements cannot do this